Are there well-established methods for the asymptotic analytical evaluation of Fourier series?
To obtain asymptotic expansions of integrals which depend on a large parameter, such as
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)\;e^{i\lambda h(x)}{\rm d}x$$
($\lambda\to\infty$), one appeals to the methods of stationary phase or of steepest descent. The expansion consists of contributions arising from the critical points $h'(x)=0$.
I wonder if asymptotic methods are also readily available for the analytical evaluation of Fourier series.
For instance, I wish to obtain a fair approximation to
$$F(\theta)=\sum_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty} f_m\;{\rm e}^{{\rm i}[m\theta+\psi(m)]}$$
The coefficients $f_m$ vary slowly with $m$ over a broad range, and finally decrease exponentially at large $|m|$. By analogy with the asymptotic evaluation of integrals, I expect the main contributions to this series to be associated with indices $\tilde{m}$ such that $\theta+\psi'(\tilde{m})=0$. But this discrete problem seems significantly different from the continuous one, since the phase factor may change rapidly when $m$ varies in discrete steps of $1$.
I haven't found anything specific on this topic in my reference applied maths textbooks, nor on the Web so far. I would much appreciate any relevant reference or hint you may have.
